# using sed to find a word in a line and replace the part next to the word

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have some test in a file like `xxxxx(HOST=xxxx.xx.com)` on a Linux machine

I want to search with HOST and replace the part after = till )

Please suggest how to do this with sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -e 's/\((HOST=\)[^()]*\()\)/\1REPLACEMENT\2/' myfile
```

If you prefer Sed to edit (alter) *myfile* in place (caution: this will change the contents of *myfile*), then:

```
sed -e 's/\((HOST=\)[^()]*\()\)/\1REPLACEMENT\2/' -i myfile
```

**HOW IT WORKS**

The `s///` is Sed's *substitution* command. Thus, `s/foo/bar/` replaces each occurrence of `foo` by `bar`.

The suggested pattern to solve your problem has three parts:

- `(HOST=`
- `[^()]*`
- `)`

The middle part matches anything that is not a parenthesis, and the asterisk `*` that ends the middle part means that *zero or more* characters that are not parentheses are to be matched. In your example, "xxxx.xx.com" is matched.

The first and last parts are `\(` captured `\)` by escaped parentheses as shown. There are two captures. In the replacement pattern, the `\1` and `\2` print the captured text. (If unsure what I have just said, try `\1\1\1` instead of `\1` and see what that does.)